# How would I turn a string of numbers and mathematical operators, into a integer answer? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, math

For example, "22+20" Would then be converted to the answer of 42, with 42 being an integer. Another example would be "20/10*4", Which the answer being 8. How would I do this?

Comment: `eval( "22+20" )` should solve it.

Comment: The quick and dirty way would be to use `eval('22+20') === 42`. But that evaluates arbitrary JavaScript, not just simple arithmetical operations. A better way would be to build a simple context-free grammar and parse these expressions to either validate them before passing it into `eval` or to just compute the result entirely yourself.

Comment: Split the string on operators, going with order of operations. Evaluate the fragments for numericity. Then perform the operations.

Comment: Have a look here: http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *easy* but *dangerous* answer is to use `eval()`, as in:

```
eval("20/10*4"); // returns 8
```

But you ***must*** validate any input you pass to `eval()`, or you will have a cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability! It will run whatever you pass it, even if the code is malicious.

You can also take the safer, but harder, route, and write a parser that interprets the string and calculates accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I know its a simple question, yet i still got downvoted ._., i am new to javascript as well as i mentioned in the post

Comment: Glad to help! It's a perfectly reasonable question for a new JavaScript programmer. :) Please remember to accept this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Like Ed Cottrell says, you can use `eval` but you will need to be very careful with that. Instead, you can use the expression parser of [math.js](http://mathjs.org/):

```
math.eval('20/10*4'); // returns 8
```